# How many factors of $N$ are a multiple of $K$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, factoring

How many factors of $N = 12^{12} \times 14^{14} \times 15^{15}$ are a multiple of $K = 12^{10} \times 14^{10} \times 15^{10}$ ?

---

Any approach to attempt such questions ?

Comment: Start by fully factorizing each...

Comment: $N = 3^{27}2^{26}7^{14}5^{15}$ and $K = 3^{20}2^{20}7^{10}5^{10}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the same as asking how many divisors for the number
$$\frac NK=2^8\cdot3^7\cdot 5^5\cdot 7^4.$$

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way:
$$N=2^{38}3^{27} 5^{15} 7^{14}$$
Now ask yourself how many factors are a multiple of:
$$K=2^{30}3^{20} 5^{10} 7^{10}$$$$

Comment: ... i.e. how many divisors $R=\frac{N}{K}=2^8 3^7 5^5 7^4$ has. We would dare to say $9\cdot 8\cdot 6\cdot 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $\;N=2^{38}\cdot3^{27}\cdot5^{15}\cdot7^{14}\;,\;\;K=2^{30}\cdot3^{20}\cdot5^{10}\cdot7^{10}\;$

You need that each multiple has at least the same ammount of prime factors as $\;K\;$ has...